# Add MySQL driver in yiicod/yii2-socketio

Tags: mysql-connector, yii2-extension

I want to implement notification feature with websockets and for that I am using yiicod/yii2-socketio but the documentation is not enough for me. There is only a default redis driver for connection and my db is on mysql. I really don't know how to create a MySQL driver for this yii2 extension.

Environment: OS: UBuntu 20.04, Database: mySQL, Backend API: Yii2, Frontend: ReactJs

If anyone of you have an experience with implementation of websockets in yii2 then please share it with me.

Thank you

I tried to create MySQL Driver but it is not working.